# How to store the value from radiobuttonlist to database in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, radiobuttonlist

I need help in storing the values from the radiobuttonlist to SQL Server 2008. My code works fine but when I checked in the database if my values from the radiobuttonlist have been stored there's nothing in the database.

asp.net

```
    <p>
       Hypertension<asp:RadioButtonList 
        ID="RadioButtonList1" 
        RepeatColumns ="2" RepeatDirection = "vertical" 
        RepeatLayout= "table" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" 
         onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
         Width="250px" Height="10px" style="margin-left: 0px" BorderStyle="None" 
          CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1">
          <asp:ListItem Value="rbtrue">TRUE</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="rbfalse">FALSE</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
   </p>
```

In C#:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
        string selectedValue1 = this.RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
        string selectedValue2 = this.RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TumorRegistryConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "Insert into tbTRcBase(HPN,HPNTreatement,ISH,ISHTreatment,Asthma,AsthmaTreatment,DM,DMTreatment,OtherCo,OtherCoTreatment,SecondHandSmoke,Smoker,StopSmoking,Occupation,CancerFamilyHistory,FamilyWithCancer,ParentWithCancer) value(@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", selectedValue1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", selectedValue2);

            try
            {
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
          }
      }
```

Comment: What is getting saved in database ?

Comment: Did the SqlCommand get executed without any error?

Comment: SQL command should be Insert into tbl () values (). You have mentioned value

Comment: already fixed that  though still no changes

Answer (score 1):

if you use this

```
string selectedValue2 = this.RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue;
```

you will get the value of the list button that is selected that is rbtrue or rbfalse

if you want to get the selected radiolistbuttons text use this

```
 string selectedValue2 = this.RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Try this query

```
string sql = "Insert into tbTRcBase(HPN,HPNTreatement,ISH,ISHTreatment,Asthma,AsthmaTreatment,DM,DMTreatment,OtherCo,OtherCoTreatment,SecondHandSmoke,Smoker,StopSmoking,Occupation,CancerFamilyHistory,FamilyWithCancer,ParentWithCancer) values(@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17)";
```

hope this helps

Comment: this works but my problem is it doesn't appear on the database

Comment: check your query there is a error you used value instead of values

Comment: thanks by the query mistake already fixed that prob, i tried the .SelectedItem.Text  property but when i try to submit the form, an error occurs on the c# codes, "mishandled nullexception"

Comment: if you don't want to pass values to remaining parameter just leave them empty and try it will work only if you allowed null values in db for all that parameters